# share folder between desktop and laptop which shares internet

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, wireless-networking

I have a laptop with windows XP and a desktop with windows 7.

I shared the wireless internet of my laptop to my desktop using a cable. This all works fine.

Now the problem is that if I make a shared folder on my laptop, it doesn't show in the network connections of the desktop, it doesn't even show the laptop itself.

Is this possible or am i doing something wrong?

```
Config wireless: automatic via DHCP.
IP: 192.168.1.2
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway and DNS: 192.168.1.1


Config LAN laptop:
192.168.1.9
255.255.255.0
DNS/gateway: 192.168.1.2

Config LAN windows 7 desktop:
192.168.1.8
255.255.255.0
gateway:192.168.1.9
DNS: 8.8.8.8 (DNS from Google, it doesn't work else..?)
```

Comment: You probably have an authorization problem on the laptop.  Either that or the folder doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 0):

Check that they're both on the same network, if so, enable homegroups and make sure they're in the same group.

Edit:

Your computer is not connecting to the gateway which your laptop is in. (192.168.1.9 vs 192.168.1.2). Get one to connect to the other and windows should see the other.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest solution, is to use Dropbox or something similar. So you can create a folder inside dropbox. Make both pc's install dropbox, and a shortcut to the folder on the desktop. They will stay synchrd.

Comment: That’s hardly ideal, it would waste 2x the size of the file(s) in bandwidth. By keeping it in the LAN, they can avoid wasting *any* external bandwidth.